# How to convert image (svg) to rendered svg in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an image that loads when clicking a div like so:

`<img class="svg" src="{{asset('public/images/my_image.svg') }}" alt="" id='image'>`

When calling this image from the backend side, it's returned as an image and not vectors (SVG render). How can I render it to SVG using Javascript or any other similar tool?

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you just want to return the content of the svg, am I right? Why not just use the `file_get_contents` method `echo file_get_contents("your_image.svg");`

Comment: See [DevTo Post ``<load-file>``](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an `img` tag with a `src` in essentially makes an HTTP request to the server for you. In this case you have to make the request yourself. You can do that with the [`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) which is native to JavaScript.

```
// This should be the path to your SVG file.
// Modify if incorrect.
const svgFilePath = 'public/images/my_image.svg';

// Select the current image.
const image = document.querySelector('.svg');

// Create a new dom parser to turn the SVG string into an element.
const parser = new DOMParser();

// Fetch the file from the server.
fetch(svgFilePath)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {

    // Turn the raw text into a document with the svg element in it.
    const parsed = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');

    // Select the <svg> element from that document.
    const svg = parsed.querySelector('svg');

    // If both the image and svg are found, replace the image with the svg.
    if (image !== null && svg !== null) {
      image.replaceWith(svg);
    }

  });
```

And with handling multiple files. In this case I've used an array with objects that hold the `id` of the image element you want to get and the `src` of the svg file.

```
// Array of object containing the id of the image you want to replace
// and the src of the SVG that takes it's place.
const svgFiles = [
  { id: 'image1', src: 'public/images/my_image_1.svg' },
  { id: 'image2', src: 'public/images/my_image_2.svg' },
  { id: 'image3', src: 'public/images/my_image_3.svg' },
];

// Create a new dom parser to turn the SVG string into an element.
const parser = new DOMParser();

// Loop over each object in the array and use the id and src
// with a destructuring assignment.
for (const { id, src } of svgFiles) {

  // Find the image. If it is not there, continue with the
  // loop to the next iteration.
  let image = document.getElementById(id);
  if (image === null) continue;

  // Fetch the file from the server.
  fetch(src)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {

      // Turn the raw text into a document with the svg element in it.
      const parsed = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');

      // Select the <svg> element from that document.
      const svg = parsed.querySelector('svg');

      // If the svg is found, replace the image with the svg.
      // Otherwise, continue the loop.
      if (svg === null) continue;
      image.replaceWith(svg);

    });
}
```

Comment: wont the SVG image be automatically rendered to vectors?

Comment: The V in SVG stands for vector. So any SVG has vectors, but you probably mean something else. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Oh, my bad, you are right. I got the vector points by printing it out (using console.log) but how can I replace the current image with the new rendered svg content?

Comment: I've modified the answer for you to be able to replace the `<img>` with the new `<svg>` element. But this method seems tedious if you simply want to replace the image with something else and should be handled from the backend. Consider finding a server side svg rendering approach.

Comment: I tried your new approach but when I refreshed the page, the image is only seen in my page but the rest of the HTML content disappeared

Comment: Do you have a `.svg` class on a parent element? Because this script replaces the first encounter of that class with the SVG.

Comment: I added a unique id to the image element and replaced .svg with #image. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210792/discussion-between-emiel-zuurbier-and-danny-boy).

Comment: What does .then(text => {}) mean?

Comment: The `text => {}` an arrow function. It's almost the same as doing `function(text) {}`. `.then()` is a promise callback. `fetch` can take a while to complete so it works with promises which can wait for a while before continuing the code. When a promise is *fulfilled*  (meaning it has finished without an error) it will call the function in the adjacent `.then()` Read up on [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: what if there are multiple images? How can you use your code for multiple dynamic images?

Comment: I've added a version that uses a loop to change all the images in the array. Replace the `id` and `src` values with your own image elements and SVG files.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are using `asset()` function so I'm guessing you don't necessary want it to be JS
You can use [Laravel SVG package](https://github.com/adamwathan/blade-svg) which provides `@svg()` blade directive.
 it's small and convenient

```php
<a href="/settings">
    @svg('cog', 'icon-lg') Settings
</a>

<!-- Renders.. -->
<a href="/settings">
    <svg class="icon icon-lg">
        <path d="..." fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
    </svg>
    Settings
</a>
```