# Is there a way to have the user upload an SVG file but then render the SVG source?

Tags: svg, razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Using 2sxc on DNN, I have a website that uses SVGs for icons in content types. The client wants to be able to upload the SVG icons to 2sxc via a Link field but then instead of rendering `<img src="@Content.SVG" />`, they want it to render the source code of the SVG (so we could manipulate the fill color via CSS). Is this even possible and how could it be done?

Comment: If it is possible, would there be a security risk to doing this?

Comment: Yes. SVG files can include scripts.  So anything your page can do, the SVG can do.  So you need to either (i) trust your users, or (ii) block files with potentially dangerous content (`<script>` elements, references to third party files/images, etc), or (iii) strip out the problematic content from those files.

Comment: I stuffed all Icon SVG data into strings; and then everything into **one** Custom Element file, which again outputs IMG or SVG, and has all styling options: https://IconMeister.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically 2 steps

1. Get the real file name using 2sxc and DNN
2. Then load the file as a string using normal .net stuff `System.IO` and add it to your html - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.5.1

ca. like this

```
<div>
 @Html.Raw(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName)
</div>
```

Comment: I can get the SVG icon like @Content.SVGIcon. How would I use System.IO to load it as a string?

Comment: Just read as text and output as html. Updated example.

Comment: I've accepted this an answer but I actually couldn't get it to work in my setup. Will have to try on a simpler project later.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples of how to do this can be found below

#### Using the fetch API

[How to convert image (svg) to rendered svg in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60985791/how-to-convert-image-svg-to-rendered-svg-in-javascript)

#### Older methods such as `XMLHttpRequest` or jQuery

[Include SVG files with HTML, and still be able to apply styles to them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783441/include-svg-files-with-html-and-still-be-able-to-apply-styles-to-them)

#### Using D3

[(Embed and) Refer to an external SVG via D3 and/or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209549/embed-and-refer-to-an-external-svg-via-d3-and-or-javascript)

#### Using a custom JS library

One example: [SVGInjector](https://github.com/iconic/SVGInjector)

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly Dnn is doing this nowadays and you can look at the code here. If you ignore the caching, you might be able to do similar in a View.
https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/0d3b931d8483b01aaad0291a5fde2cbc0bac60ca/DNN%20Platform/Website/admin/Skins/Logo.ascx.cs#L123

And that is called from above, see ~line 71, so they are doing a real inject of the file contents to inline. Obviously caching file-access stuff should be a priority for caching if the website is high-traffic, but otherwise it is not needed or at least secondary.