# How to get svg icon as a string from a .svg file

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there a way to get svg icon as a string while you have the `.svg` file with JavaScript ?

To be more clear, I need a function which does:

```
function svgFileToString('./icon.svg'){
...
...
return `<svg>...</svg>`
}
```

Comment: I think that this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60985791/how-to-convert-image-svg-to-rendered-svg-in-javascript) can answer what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: See [DevTo Post ``<load-file>``](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) function. The function `svgFileToString()` will not return anything, but you can replace `console.log(text);` with whatever.

For the example I'm using a data URL to replace the real path to a file.

```js
function svgFileToString(iconpath){
  fetch(iconpath)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
      console.log(text);
      // do whatever
    });
}

//svgFileToString('/icon.svg');

// for testing here on ST:

svgFileToString('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1MCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI1MCI+CiAgPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgZmlsbD0iZ3JlZW4iIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPgo=');
```

Comment: Correct. you can also use `require(path_to_icon)`  as `iconpath` which returns the base64 format of the file given.